# How do I keep the selected button highlighted?

Tags: html, css

I have two buttons located in the header of my website. By default the first button "Admin" I want it to be highlighted, but when I click the second one I want to highlight the second one and so on. How do I go about that?

```
<div style="float:right;">     
   <button type="button" class="active_admin_button active_admin_button2" onclick="active_admin_button_request()">Active admins</button>
   <button type="button" class="deactivated_admin_button deactivated_admin_button2" onclick="deactivated_admin_button_request()">Deactivated admins</button>
</div>
```

The CSS styling I am using for both buttons, and as you can see I am highlighting when hover but I want to keep that highlight when clicked:

```
 .active_admin_button {
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        border: none;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 16px;
        transition-duration: 0.2s;
        cursor: pointer;
        height: 40px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        border-top-left-radius: 6px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
        width: 160px;
    }

    .active_admin_button2 {
        background-color: white;
        color: black;
        border: 2px solid #008CBA;
    }

    .active_admin_button2:hover {
        background-color: #008CBA;
        color: white;
    }


    .deactivated_admin_button {
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        border: none;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 16px;
        transition-duration: 0.2s;
        cursor: pointer;
        height: 40px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        border-top-right-radius: 6px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
        width: 160px;
    }

    .deactivated_admin_button2 {
        background-color: white;
        color: black;
        border: 2px solid #008CBA;
    }

    .deactivated_admin_button2:hover {
        background-color: #008CBA;
        color: white;
    }
```

Comment: do you mean CSS `:focus` or `:active` instead of `:hover`? or should it be permanently changed, so after clicking somewhere else on the page it still remains highlighted?

Comment: Sounds to me as though you want a *radio button* not a simple button

Comment: @RamondeVries exactly! I want the highlight to change when clicked. So the clicked button should remain highlighted until the next button is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a few changes to your code:

firstly, I added an id to each of your buttons and named them `btn1` and `btn2` respectively.

Then, I changed your classes in a way that 1st button gets `activeBtn` class and 2nd button gets `deactiveBtn` class. These classes has the following stylings:

```
.activeBtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
    width: 160px;
}


.activeBtn:hover {
background-color: #008CBA!important;
color: white;
}

.deactiveBtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 6px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
    width: 160px;
}

deactiveBtn:hover{
    background-color: #008CBA!important;
    color: white!important;
}
```

After that, another class was defined which has the stylings of any button that is not selected (The user has not clicked on it yet):

```
.btnDeactivated {
    background-color: white!important;
    color: black!important;
    border: 2px solid #008CBA!important;
}

.btnDeactivated:hover {
    background-color: #008CBA!important;
    color: white;
}
```

Finally, as you mentioned that you want the first button activated at startup I gave the `btnDeactivated` class to the second button. So, the HTML code looks like:

```
<div style="float:right;">     
   <button type="button" id="btn1" class="activeBtn" onclick="btnFunc1()">Active admins</button>
   <button type="button" id="btn2" class="deactiveBtn btnDeactivated" onclick="btnFunc2()">Deactivated admins</button>
</div>
```

For java-script, I just defined a function for each button. What each function functions does is when the user clicks on a button it checks if that button contains `btnDeactivated` class. If yes, first of all it removes it and then adds it to the other button. This way the risk of getting a java-script error is handled in cases that the user clicks on a button twice. These functions look like:

Therefor the final code will look like something below (I didn't include `activeBtn:hover` and `deactiveBtn:hover` in the main code as I thought you need the hover effect only on the deactivated button. If you want it on both, you can add it.):

```css
 .activeBtn {
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        border: none;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 16px;
        transition-duration: 0.2s;
        cursor: pointer;
        height: 40px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        border-top-left-radius: 6px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
        width: 160px;
    }

    
        .btnDeactivated {
        background-color: white!important;
        color: black!important;
        border: 2px solid #008CBA!important;
    }
    

    
    .btnDeactivated:hover {
        background-color: #008CBA!important;
        color: white;
    }


    .deactiveBtn {
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        border: none;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 16px;
        transition-duration: 0.2s;
        cursor: pointer;
        height: 40px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        border-top-right-radius: 6px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
        width: 160px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>

</head>
<body>

<div style="float:right;">     
   <button type="button" id="btn1" class="activeBtn" onclick="btnFunc1()">Active admins</button>
   <button type="button" id="btn2" class="deactiveBtn btnDeactivated" onclick="btnFunc2()">Deactivated admins</button>
</div>
<script>
function btnFunc1(){
    document.getElementById("btn1").classList.remove("btnDeactivated");
    document.getElementById("btn2").classList.add("btnDeactivated");
}

function btnFunc2(){
    document.getElementById("btn2").classList.remove("btnDeactivated");
    document.getElementById("btn1").classList.add("btnDeactivated");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Conditional checking if an element has classname in classList is redundant in that context.

Comment: @EvgheniCalcutin what if the user clicks twice on the same button?

Comment: @EvgheniCalcutin You are right add() and remove() functions won't work if the class name already exists or the class name has already been removed, respectively. I edited the answer. Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 2):

Just try the below example. It will allow you to add multiple buttons and Highlighting will change on the clicks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<style>
.ButtonState{display:none}
.Button{padding:3px; margin:4px; background:#CCC; border:1px solid #333; 
cursor:pointer;}
.ButtonState:checked + .Button{background:#fff;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<input type="radio" name="Button" class="ButtonState" checked id="Button1" value="1"/>
<label class="Button" for="Button1">Button 1</label>
<input type="radio" name="Button" class="ButtonState" id="Button2" value="2"/>
<label class="Button" for="Button2">Button 2</label>
<input type="radio" name="Button" class="ButtonState" id="Button3" value="3"/>
<label class="Button" for="Button3">Button 3</label>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Although the question was asked considering that JS will be used to solve the issue and the stylings of the buttons that you have designed are not the same, your answer was awesome and I really appreciate the idea of using radio buttons this way. Congratulations. 

Answer (score 1):

Programatically add classname to the button you click and remove classname from another button.

```js
let firstBtn = document.getElementById('first');
let secondBtn = document.getElementById('second');

firstBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    firstBtn.classList.add('highlight');
  secondBtn.classList.remove('highlight');
});

secondBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    secondBtn.classList.add('highlight');
  firstBtn.classList.remove('highlight');
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<button id="first" class="highlight">First</button>
<button id="second">Second</button>
```

Comment: I will give it a try and let you know, it seems like this will do! Thanks!

Comment: it did but I selected another answer as the right one because its closer to the styling I used